# Return string instead of int

Tags: c, return, return-value, return-type, cs50

When I print out a pyramid, the last line of the pyramid or the base prints out an integer which represents how many hashes, instead of a string of hashes.

like such:

Height: 3

```
#
##
3
```

when its supposed to be:

```
Height 3:

#
##
###
```

I'm supposed to print out a pyramid with a height based on the user's input, but instead of the base being printed out as a string it prints out an integer of how many hashes there should be for the base. I understand that this is because I'm returning n but I don't know how to go about it in a way where it still returns the loop.

I've tried changing the class to void instead of int, but that throws an error as it's conflicting types. I'm thinking I should print out an empty string but it messes with my bounds.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int get_height(string prompt);

int main(void)
{

    int ask = get_height("Height: ");
    printf("%i\n", ask);

}

int get_height(string prompt) {

    int n;
    do {
        n = get_int("%s", prompt);
    }
    while (n < 1 || n > 8);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return n; 
}
```

Comment: `get_height` is doing a lot more than just getting a height. Maybe keep it simple and actually print the pyramid somewhere *else* in your program. If it isn't obvious where the numeric print is coming from, you may need to review your class notes, because the height is numeric printed in only one place in this code.

Comment: In general, if the first thing your program does is prompt for a parameter, consider instead passing that parameter as an argument.  (Don't just consider it; do it.  I'm trying to be diplomatic.)  Consider how clunky `grep` would be if it prompted you for a pattern to match, or `ls` if it prompted you for a directory.

Comment: Also notice that the line `while (n < 1 || n > 8);` means "if the user entered a number out of range, sit in an infinite loop doing nothing". Maybe not what you intended?

Comment: `while (n < 1 || n > 8);` is an infinite loop if n is not in [1,8]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line of output is the height because that is the last thing printed in your `main` function:

```
printf("%i\n", ask);
```

`get_height` will actually only print `n-1` lines because the first iteration (i=0,j=0) is skipped.

Answer (score 0):

the 3 should be output

The problem is this statement;

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
```

which stops too early. Suggest:

```
for (int j = i; j >=0; j--) {
```

The output after making the above change:

```
#
##
###
3
```